# Calling a variable with space in a function

Tags: variables, nightwatch.js

As part of my **nightwatchjs** test script, I have the following variable defined;

```
var makeUpperCase = "Land Rover";
```

This variable is then referenced in a separate script;

```
exports.list_of_all_the_colour_seo_crawl_path_links = function(makeUpperCase, solrdevcfsclient, callback) {
  var seoCrawlPathLinksColourQuery = solrdevcfsclient.createQuery()
    .q("*:*")
    .start(0)
    .rows(1)
    .matchFilter("ManufacturerName",`${makeUpperCase}`)

    .matchFilter("NewOrUsed", "Used")
    .facet({
      field:"GenericColour",
      mincount:"1"
    });
  solrdevcfsclient.search(seoCrawlPathLinksColourQuery,function(err,obj) {
    if(err) {
      callback(err,null);
    }
    else {
      callback(null, obj.facet_counts.facet_fields);
    }
  });
};
```

However, this is failing.

Which I'm presuming is due to the space between the 'Land' and 'Rover'?

So, how can I reference this variable with a space within my other script (${makeUpperCase}).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I could very well be mistaken about this, but from looking at what you posted, it seems like the issue could just be that you're using a template literal unnecessarily. So, instead of using `` .matchFilter("ManufacturerName",`${makeUpperCase}`) `` could you try `.matchFilter("ManufacturerName", makeUpperCase)`? I'm not sure where you're calling `list_of_all_the_colour_seo_crawl_path_links`, but you should just be able to use your variable as the first argument for it, and that should pass it into the function for you. Hope that helps.